# WooCommerce product additional information shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, custom-taxonomy

I am new to WooCommerce and am looking for a solution to display **Product attributes** on a post page.
I've made research and some test but nothing seems to work.

Ideally, I would like to use a **shortcode** taking the **Product ID** and displaying all his product attributes on my post page. 
something like `[product_page id="99" display_only_attributes ]`

Comment: i just want them displayed on my post page (blog) as they normally are on the product page. But only the additional information section ( the attributes ). No html, just with wordpress back-end.

The goal is that the content team of my company would be able to use any product entered in woocommerce and display its attributes in the middle of a post page.

It is for a simple product which would also display variations.

Comment: So you want to display all attributes on product listing page, product wise.

Comment: Well not on product page, but on a post page. 
We currently are building a website of car reviews. Each cars will be entered into woocommerce, with all the specificated attributes associated to each car. The reviews are written as normal blog post.
When the content team is writting a review about a car, i would like them to be able to use a shortcode referring to the car ID entered in woocommerce, that would list all its attributes in the article

Comment: working perfectly ! Merci beaucoup :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the way to get the product attributes in a custom shortcode where you will define the product ID in as a shortcode argument **`id`**.

The function code:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'display_product_additional_information' ) ) {

    function display_product_additional_information($atts) {

        // Shortcode attribute (or argument)
        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'id'    => ''
        ), $atts, 'product_additional_information' );

        // If the "id" argument is not defined, we try to get the post Id
        if ( ! ( ! empty($atts['id']) && $atts['id'] > 0 ) ) {
           $atts['id'] = get_the_id();
        }
        
        // We check that the "id" argument is a product id
        if ( get_post_type($atts['id']) === 'product' ) {
            $product = wc_get_product($atts['id']);
        }
        // If not we exit
        else {
            return;
        }

        ob_start(); // Start buffering

        do_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', $product );

        return ob_get_clean(); // Return the buffered outpout
    }

    add_shortcode('product_additional_information', 'display_product_additional_information');

}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**SHORTCODE USAGE** *(Updated)*

1. with a defined product id:

   ```
    [product_additional_information id='37']
   ```

   Or in php:

   ```
    echo do_shortcode("[product_additional_information id='37']");
   ```
2. In an existing product page *(when "additional information" product tab is removed for example)*:

   ```
    [product_additional_information]
   ```

   Or in php:

   ```
    echo do_shortcode("[product_additional_information]");
   ```

You will get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Code did not work because of space in shortcode parameter.

```
add_shortcode('product_additional_information', 'display_product_additional_information');
```

correct is :

```
add_shortcode(' product_additional_information', 'display_product_additional_information' );
```

Comment: Your explanation seems to mean that a blank should be removed. But the solution you show adds one.